# Const on print of mutable object

Tags: c

Is it necessary to declare a mutable object `const` if the function does not modify it, or is this a redundancy that is not required? For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print_num_ptr(const int *n) {
    printf("Example print: %d", *n);
}
int main(void) {
    int i=4;
    int *ptr_i=&i;
    print_num_ptr((const int*)ptr_i);
    (*ptr_i) ++;
    print_num_ptr((const int*)ptr_i);

}
```

Vs.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print_num_ptr(int *n) {
    printf("Example print: %d", *n);
}
int main(void) {
    int i=4;
    int *ptr_i=&i;
    print_num_ptr(ptr_i);
    (*ptr_i) ++;
    print_num_ptr(ptr_i);
}
```

The first one just seems like a lot of headache unless there's a reason to use it over the first.

Comment: It's one extra word, not "a lot of headache" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good habit to declare unchanging arguments as `const` both to advertise in the function signature that you *will not* change them, and to allow the compiler to optimize around that parameter.

Any function with a non-`const` argument implies it can or will modify that value, which if not true, communicates your intentions incorrectly.

Adding `const` to everything might seem like a useless ritual, but it has a very important function.

> As a note, it's usually not necessary to cast *to* a `const` version of same. The compiler does that for you automatically. `const` acts as a safety that's implicitly applied, but won't be removed without going out of your way to break it off.

Comment: perhaps I have some compiler warnings on (using GCC), but usually when passing a mutable object to a function that takes it as `const` it'll often give a warning. When does it / does it not give warnings for casting to `const`? (Or maybe it's when it casts from a const to a non-const where it gives warnings?)

Comment: Casting to `const` should happen implicitly for a given `x*` being passed into a function caking `const x*`. If you get an error, it might be something else, so do you have an example?

Comment: @carl.hiass: Casting from `const` to non-`const` definitely should give a warning, so probably that's what you're thinking of.  Hopefully it's clear why one is okay and the other not: deciding not to modify something that is able to be modified, is fine.  Trying to modify something that should not be modified, is bad.